# ng-if runs before the time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a custom Soundcloud player made with Plangular: a directive that uses AngularJS and Soundcloud API.
Since a lot of Soundcloud tracks are not streamable by third part apps (the GET request returns nothing) and basically they don't work over this player, I'm trying to check with a `ng-if="track"` and `ng-if="!track"` if the track is correctly loaded or not, and show a different content. 
This is working great, however when you load the page, even if the track is streamable (like the one in my example) it is not loaded on the DOM yet, so for just a couple of seconds I see the content of the negative condition (`ng-if="!track"`). Is there any trick I can do to avoid this? Maybe is possible to slow down the check of ng-if?

Here is my html code, the `{{loading}}` is declared in the controller:

```
<body ng-app="player" ng-controller="SearchBar">
  <div plangular="https://soundcloud.com/ghostbeach/fickle-friends-for-you-ghost-beach-remix-1" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-if="!track"  class="flex flex-center" ng-cloak>
      <i class="fa fa-cog fa-spin fa-1x fa-fw mr1" ng-cloak></i>
      <div class="mr1" ng-cloak>{{loading}}</div>
    </div>
    <!-- close ng-if not streamable -->
    <div class="flex flex-center" ng-if="track">
      <div  class="mr1">
        <img ng-src="{{track.artwork_url}}" alt="{{track.title}}" style="height:60px; width: 60px;" ng-cloak/>
      </div>
      <div ng-click="playPause()"
        title="Play/Pause"
        class="flex-none h0 mr1 button-transparent cursor button-grow">
        <svg ng-if="player.playing !== track.src" class="icon geomicon" data-icon="play" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" >
          <path d="M4 4 L28 16 L4 28 z "></path>
        </svg>
        <svg ng-if="player.playing === track.src" class="icon geomicon" data-icon="pause" viewBox="0 0 32 32" width="32" height="32" >
          <path d="M4 4 H12 V28 H4 z M20 4 H28 V28 H20 z "></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-auto">
        <div class="h5 bold mr2">
          <a target="_blank" ng-href="{{track.permalink_url}}">{{track.title}}</a>
        </div>
        <progress
          class="progress orange"
          ng-click="seek($event)"
          ng-value="currentTime / duration || 0">
        {{ currentTime / duration }}
        </progress>     
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- close nf-if streamable-->
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is my JS:

```
var player = angular.module('player', ['plangular'])
   .config(function(plangularConfigProvider){
   plangularConfigProvider.clientId = 'XXX';
});
player.controller('SearchBar', ['$scope',function ($scope){ 
        $scope.loading="Track is not streamable";
}]);
```

The behavior is more clear in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0fbe5q8/12/), when you run the jsfiddle it shows for a couple of seconds the negative condition of `ng-if`, I would like to avoid that.

EDIT:

Is it possible maybe to set a timeout on a ng-show to the content of ng-if?

Comment: this logic is expected, unfortunately.  Plangular uses an async method to fetch the track, so the UI doesn't block while the track is being loaded.  Until the track is fetched and the async method returns, `track` is indeed `undefined`.  The only way to handle this more gracefully would be to modify Plangular to return an error rather than `undefined` when the track is inaccessible, and perform a separate check for this error code.  Right now, Plangular only provides a "loading" state and a "playing" state.

Comment: I can't recreate with your demo.

Comment: @Claies this is exactly what I was afraid of. I didn't want to edit the plangular code though, I was looking for some tricky way...

Comment: @floor which behavior do you have?

Comment: @GoingSolo The fiddle for me always showed the loading section. And eventually errors out for loading the track. Maybe to many people using the fiddle at once. Based on your edit, you could create a custom directive which would delay showing something.

Comment: @floor maybe the track is geoblocked from your state. Try to make this get request and see if you get any response: https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/ghostbeach/fickle-friends-for-you-ghost-beach-remix-1&client_id=5d2f5dc1e07ff93b4a75bbed1e9eafdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Plangular uses an async method to fetch the track, you can't handle this logic unless to add a return error when the tracks is not sreamable.